# Block content for passing variables from python to HTML

Tags: html, django, python-3.x, jinja2

I'm trying to send some data from my python code to the HTML script.
This is my python code. I use lists to send the data.

```
def extractMetaData(request):
pdfDir = "C:/PythonPrograms/pdf/"
if pdfDir == "": pdfDir = os.getcwd() + "\\"
pdf_title = []
pdf_author = []
pdf_creationdate = []
pdf_creator = []
pdf_Keywords = []
pdf_producer = []
for pdf in os.listdir(pdfDir):
    fileExtension = pdf.split(".")[-1]
    if fileExtension == "pdf":
        pdfFilename = pdfDir + pdf 
        pdf_toread = PdfFileReader(open(pdfFilename, "rb"))
        pdf_title.append(pdf_toread.getDocumentInfo().title)
        pdf_author.append(pdf_toread.getDocumentInfo().author)
        pdf_creationdate.append(pdf_toread.getDocumentInfo()['/CreationDate'])
        pdf_creator.append(pdf_toread.getDocumentInfo()['/Creator'])
        pdf_Keywords.append(pdf_toread.getDocumentInfo()['/Keywords'])
        pdf_producer.append(pdf_toread.getDocumentInfo().producer)
return render(request,'personal/extract.html',{'content':[str(pdf_title),str(pdf_author),str(pdf_creationdate), str(pdf_creator),str(pdf_Keywords), str(pdf_producer)]})
```

In HTML I use the following code.

```
{% block content %}
{% for c in content%}

<p>{{c}}</p>

{% endfor%}
{% endblock %}
```

But this prints all the items of the first list and then all items of second list and so on.. I want it to print the first item of the first list, first item of the second list and so on. Then start with second item of every list.. how can do this in jinja?

Comment: I think you should use two forloop. One for the pdf files, and another one for every items.

Comment: That doesn't work. It prints character by character.

Comment: I explained better in my answer.

Comment: My suggestion is to prepare data in Python and then pass the ordered lists to the template. Simply iterate on the list and save items in a new list taking care of the index. In this way, you will avoid complex logic from the template.

Comment: @Benbb96 thanks for the suggestion! but still the template part doesnt work. python is sending the data as a single block. unable to access any attributes.

Comment: @Dos thanks for the suggestion. i think thats the only way left

Comment: @Cheryl What do you mean by a single block? if you try to print `pdf_files` before rendering the templates, do you get a list of pdf file with their attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this :

```
def extractMetaData(request):
    pdfDir = "C:/PythonPrograms/pdf/"
    if pdfDir == "":
        pdfDir = os.getcwd() + "\\"
        pdf_files = []
        for pdf in os.listdir(pdfDir):
            pdf_file = {}  # Create a dictionnary to store values
            fileExtension = pdf.split(".")[-1]
            if fileExtension == "pdf":
                pdfFilename = pdfDir + pdf 
                pdf_toread = PdfFileReader(open(pdfFilename, "rb"))
                pdf_file['title'] = pdf_toread.getDocumentInfo().title
                pdf_file['author'] = pdf_toread.getDocumentInfo().author
                pdf_file['creationdate'] = pdf_toread.getDocumentInfo()['/CreationDate']
                pdf_file['creator'] = pdf_toread.getDocumentInfo()['/Creator']
                pdf_file['keywords'] = pdf_toread.getDocumentInfo()['/Keywords']
                pdf_file['producer'] = pdf_toread.getDocumentInfo().producer
                pdf_files.append(pdf_file)
    return render(request,'personal/extract.html', {'pdf_files': pdf_files})
```

And then in the template :

```
{% block content %}
{% for pdf in pdf_files %}
    {% for item_name, item in pdf_file.items %}
        <p>{{ item_name }} : {{ item }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor%}
<hr>
{% endblock %}
```

I didn't test it so it might have some errors..

Comment: thank you so much. made some changes and it worked. 
{% block content %}
{% for pdf in pdf_files %}
 <p> {{pdf}} </p>
{% endfor%}
{% endblock %}